# How to query cheerio for html output inclusive of the selector tags

Tags: javascript

If you use `$("body").html()` cheerio returns the html inside the body tags. How can I query cheerio for the `body` content inclusive of the opening and closing `body` tags?

Take for example a file like this:

```
<body class="body">
 <div>
  <h1>Foo Bar</h1>
 </div>
</body>

<style>
.body {
 margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

The following code will output the `html` contents of `body`. The output will not include the `<body>` tags, which is what I want to achieve

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const $ = cheerio.load(text);
const body = $("body").html();

console.log(body);
// <div>
//  <h1>Foo Bar</h1>
// </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.html("body")` instead of `$("body").html()`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://cheerio.js.org/docs/basics/loading#load, use a third argument as `false` while loading the `text`:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(text, null, false);
```